# SQL LEFT JOIN - Combine arrays with the same id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, left-join

I'm writing a MySQL query (with laravel Query Builder) with multiple LEFT JOIN. In the result the array I get looks like:

```
    array:4 [▼
  0 => {#322 ▼
    +"id": 19
    +"thing_id": 7
    +"title": "new translate"
    +"locale": "en"
    +"thing_sub_cat_id": 19
    +"name": "WINTER"
  }
  1 => {#323 ▼
    +"id": 24
    +"thing_id": 7
    +"title": "new translate"
    +"locale": "en"
    +"thing_sub_cat_id": 24
    +"name": "DIVING"
  }
  2 => {#324 ▼
    +"id": 37
    +"thing_id": 15
    +"title": "thing to do"
    +"locale": "en"
    +"thing_sub_cat_id": 37
    +"name": "LATEST HAPPENINGS"
  }
  3 => {#325 ▼
    +"id": 21
    +"thing_id": 2
    +"title": "Main page"
    +"locale": null
    +"thing_sub_cat_id": null
    +"name": null
  }
]
```

**Query Builder**:

```
DB::table('things_translations')
                            ->leftjoin('things_sub_cat_rel', 'things_sub_cat_rel.thing_id', '=', 'things_translations.thing_id')
                            ->leftjoin('things_sub_cat_translations', 'things_sub_cat_rel.thing_sub_cat_id', '=', 'things_sub_cat_translations.thing_sub_cat_id')
                            ->where('things_translations.locale', '=', 'en')
                            ->get();
```

The `locale` column associate with [laravel-translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) package. I'm trying to get all rows of database that has `locale=en`. I'd use laravel eloquent but I got `unknown column locale` so I've tried the query builder above.

**Associated models**:

`ThingTranslation` that has belongsToMany relation with `ThingSubCat`. For example let's say that I have 3 tables 1 for articles 1 for categories and 1 for relation that has the articleID and categoryID.

I would like to know the better way to combine arrays that has the same "thing_id". For example above I have two arrays with the thing_id: 7. Can I combine these two arrays to one using mysql and for the "name" to have multiple arrays with it's value ?

Comment: Show us your query built in laravel, along with its associated models. The result depends on how you structured your models & relationships.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my answer if you want more details tell me.

Comment: #Mysteryos at first I've tried with Eloquent but I have problem with "locale".  The locale is builded because of that module: https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable I had used Eloquent with where clause to get only the "en" locale but  it does't work, so I've turned to query builder

Comment: You should use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function to achive this. I'll write the SQL. the transformation in laravel is on yours ;)

Comment: Your translation table should have only one foreign key, given that it has been created by the `laravel-translatable` package. By inserting a `thing_sub_cat_id` key in the table, you are subverting from the package's purpose. If you truly have a need for that key, you should consider forking the package and coding your own requirements into it. As for the matter at hand, you should query `thing` first by eloquent, and eager-load the `thing_sub_cat` relationship with it. Both `thing` & `thing_sub_cat` will have translations available as per your need through the `laravel-translatable` package

Comment: Thank you very much. If I make something like that: `Thing::with('subCategories')->get();`I get the subcategories normally. The problem is when I want to add where clause like that: `$getThing = Thing::with('subCategories')->where('locale', 'en')->get();` it gives me Unknown column 'locale'.. but locale exist. If I try any other field in where clause it works, only the locale is the problem. That is the reason that I turned into the query builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If someone has the same problem with laravel he can look at my answers below. If someone has similar problem, he can try with the query in the answer of Ramin Omrani. It works perfect.

I've found the solution with laravel eloquent. The problem it was because I'm using [laravel-translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) package. And the only way to take the rows that has locale = "en" is using the `whereHas` `translations` and then with where clause like the code bellow:

```
$getThing = Thing::with('subCategories')->whereHas('translations', function ($query) {
    $query->where('locale', '=', 'en');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `GROUP_CONCAT` function in mysql like this :

```
SELECT tbl.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`name` SEPERATOR ',') as `name_combined`
    FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM things_translations
  LEFT JOIN things_sub_cat_rel ON things_sub_cat_rel.thing_id = things_translations.thing_id
  LEFT JOIN things_sub_cat_translations ON things_sub_cat_rel.thing_sub_cat_id = things_sub_cat_translations.thing_sub_cat_id
  WHERE things_translations.locale = 'en'
) tbl
GROUP BY things_id;
```

With a query like this you combine `name` in rows that their `thing_id` are alike into one row.

**Syntax Reference :**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thank you. I've tried that, it works, but I take only the `name_combined`, no the others fields... Maybe I made something wrong with laravel query builder

Comment: @Panagiotis try to execute Raw query

Comment: I've posted my answer